# Pause until external window handle is either closed or button pressed

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Handle of both the main window and of a button for an external application. I need my program to wait for either the button to be clicked or the window to be closed before my application can continue its logic. What's the best approach for accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Edit: This was needed for sollution

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use some sort of code like this.

```
while (SomeWindow.IsActive); // Perform loops until SomeWindow is active
```

Comment: Thanks actually ended up finding the answer after i posted lol